# Java Regex: how to capture multiple matches in the same line

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match a regex pattern in Java, and I have two questions:

1. Inside the pattern I'm looking for there is a known beginning and then an unknown string that I want to get up until the first occurrence of an &.
2. there are multiple occurrences of these patterns in the line and I would like to get each occurrence separately.

For example I have this input line:

```
1234567 100,110,116,129,139,140,144,146 http://www.gold.com/shc/s/c_10153_12605_Computers+%26+Electronics_Televisions?filter=Screen+Refresh+Rate%7C120HZ%5EScreen+Size%7C37+in.+to+42+in.&sName=View+All&viewItems=25&subCatView=true   ISx20070515x00001a          http://www.gold.com/shc/s/c_10153_12605_Computers+%26+Electronics_Televisions?filter=Screen+Refresh+Rate%7C120HZ&sName=View+All&subCatView=true 0   2819357575609397706
```

And I am interested in these strings:

```
Screen+Refresh+Rate%7C120HZ%5EScreen+Size%7C37+in.+to+42+in.

Screen+Refresh+Rate%7C120HZ
```

Answer (score 14):

Assuming the known beginning is `filter=**`, the regular expression pattern `(?:filter=\\*\\*)(.*?)(?:&)` should get you what you need.  Use `Matcher.find()` to get all occurrences of the pattern in a given string.  Using the test string you provided, the following:

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:filter=\\*\\*)(.*?)(?:&)");
final Matcher m = p.matcher(testString);
int cnt = 0;
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(++cnt + ": G1: " + m.group(1));
}
```

Will output:

```
1: G1: Screen+Refresh+Rate%7C120HZ%5EScreen+Size%7C37+in.+to+42+in.
2: G1: Screen+Refresh+Rate%7C120HZ**
```

Comment: Could you please include the testString so we can try this out for real? (The given testString from the OP does not work with this code)

Answer (score 2):

If i know that I might need other query parameters in the future, I think it'll be more prudent to decode and parse the URL.

```
String url = URLDecoder.decode("http://www.gold.com/shc/s/c_10153_12605_" +
            "Computers+%26+Electronics_Televisions?filter=Screen+Refresh+Rate" +
            "%7C120HZ%5EScreen+Size%7C37+in.+to+42+in.&sName=View+All&viewItems=25&subCatView=true"
            ,"utf-8");
Pattern amp = Pattern.compile("&");
Pattern eq = Pattern.compile("=");
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
String queryString = url.substring(url.indexOf('?') + 1);
for(String param : amp.split(queryString)) {
    String[] pair = eq.split(param);
    params.put(pair[0], pair[1]);
}
for(Entry<String, String> param : params.entrySet()) {
    System.out.format("%s = %s\n", param.getKey(), param.getValue());
}
```

Output

```
subCatView = true
viewItems = 25
sName = View All
filter = Screen Refresh Rate|120HZ^Screen Size|37 in. to 42 in.
```

Answer (score 1):

in your example, there is sometimes a "**" at the end before the "&".  but basically, (assuming "filter=" is the start pattern you are looking for) you want something like:

`"filter=([^&]+)&"`

Comment: I see the positive look ahead was exactly what i needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using the regular expression `(?<=filter=\*{0,2})[^&]*[^&*]+` in java:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=filter=\\*{0,2})[^&]*[^&*]+");
String s = "1234567 100,110,116,129,139,140,144,146 http://www.gold.com/shc/s/c_10153_12605_Computers+%26+Electronics_Televisions?filter=**Screen+Refresh+Rate%7C120HZ%5EScreen+Size%7C37+in.+to+42+in.&sName=View+All**&viewItems=25&subCatView=true   ISx20070515x00001a          http://www.gold.com/shc/s/c_10153_12605_Computers+%26+Electronics_Televisions?filter=**Screen+Refresh+Rate%7C120HZ**&sName=View+All&subCatView=true 0   2819357575609397706";
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

EDIT:

Added `[^&*]+` to the end of the regex to prevent the `**` from being included in the second match.

EDIT2:

Changed regular expression to use lookbehind.

Answer (score 0):

The regex you're looking for is

```
Screen\+Refresh\+Rate[^&]*
```

You could use [`Matcher.find()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) to find all matches.

Comment: thanks,but this was a specific example for a general case that will hold other strings. the sure thing is that I want to get the string from the filter= up to the first &

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for a string that follows with "filter=" and ignores the first "*" and is end with the first "&".
your can try the following:

```
String str = "1234567 100,110,116,129,139,140,144,146 http://www.gold.com/shc/s/c_10153_12605_Computers+%26+Electronics_Televisions?filter=**Screen+Refresh+Rate%7C120HZ%5EScreen+Size%7C37+in.+to+42+in.&sName=View+All**&viewItems=25&subCatView=true   ISx20070515x00001a          http://www.gold.com/shc/s/c_10153_12605_Computers+%26+Electronics_Televisions?filter=**Screen+Refresh+Rate%7C120HZ**&sName=View+All&subCatView=true 0   2819357575609397706";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("filter=(?:\\**)([^&]+?)(?:\\**)&");

    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(str);
    while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```